# While attempting to stack cards in a list, the text from the one below is showing up above the next?

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a stack of cards in a list, so that the cards can be swapped position-wise and organized.

However, while the ordering is not working either, right now I'm facing the problem of text from the card below showing up above the top-most card:

[image]

This is the code I have so far, for both the HTML and the CSS:

```css
.catCards {
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 256px;
}

.cwColumnCard {
  margin-top: -190px;
}

.cwCard {
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  border: #FFF solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3d3d3d;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
  z-index: 50;
}

.cwCTitle {
  padding: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cwImage {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cwValue {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cwSystemLabel {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="catCards">
  <ul>
    <li class="cwCard cwColumnCard">
      <div class="cwCTitle">Card One</div>
      <div class="cwImage">Test</div>
      <div class="cwValue">100</div>
      <div class="cwSystemLabel">Label</div>
    </li>
    <li class="cwCard cwColumnCard">
      <div class="cwCTitle">Card Two</div>
      <div class="cwImage">Test</div>
      <div class="cwValue">100</div>
      <div class="cwSystemLabel">Label</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Z-Index was a brief attempt to fix the text positioning, but had no effect on it. What is causing the text to show up in this manner? The card below should be hidden once it's covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `z-index` property to work correctly you need to set the `position` property to something other than `static`.

In this case adding `position: relative;` to `.cwCard` will solve your issue.

```
.cwCard {
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    border: #FFF solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px #000000cb;
    z-index: 50;
    position: relative;
}
```